# Javascript "this" losing context in IE

Tags: javascript, prototype, this

The following works fine in firefox/safari/chrome, in IE, "this" appears to be losing context in the handleEvent() function...the result of the alert is [object Window], which is not what I want; when output from handleEvent(), "this" needs to be a reference to the HandleClick object, not the Window object.

Am I missing something basic which is causing this in IE?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
HandleClick = function(el) {
    this.element = document.getElementById(el);
    if( this.element.addEventListener ) {
        this.element.addEventListener("click", this, false);
    } else {
        if( this.element.attachEvent ) {
            this.element.attachEvent("onclick", this.handleEvent);
        }
    }
}
HandleClick.prototype = {
    handleEvent: function(e) {
        alert(this);
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="new HandleClick('logo')"></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Excellent first question. Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 6):

`.attachEvent()` doesn't give you `this` as the element. You'd need to wrap the handler in a function that invokes it from the context of the element to which it is attached.

```
    if( this.element.attachEvent ) {
        var that = this;
        this.element.attachEvent("onclick", function() { 
                                              that.handleEvent.call( that.element );
                                           } );
    }
```

Comment: I tried the above suggestion, and that.handleEvent.call() doesn't seem to work as expected (in ie) in this context; however that.handleEvent( that.element ) does work. Even though I can successfully call that.handleEvent(), it doesn't seem to pass the "event" (or "e") parameter.

Any suggestions?

Comment: @ahallerblu: Works fine for me in IE. Which version are you using? To pass an `event` object as a parameter in IE, you need to reference `window.event`. So I'd change the call to `that.handleEvent.call( that.element, window.event );` Or if you didn't want to do it with `.call()`, but instead wanted to pass the element as an argument as you did, then just add in the `event` object. `that.handleEvent( that.element, window.event )`

Comment: I'm using ie8. Anyway, I didn't know I could use window.event like that. I ended up doing `that.handleEvent(window.event,that)` since using .call wasn't properly passing the second parameter for me.

Comment: @ahallerblu: Strange that `.call()` wasn't working. I'll have to do some testing. Anyway glad you found something workable.